# Выдача случайной непрочитанной записи

Tags: php, mysql, случайные-числа

Всем привет.

Суть вопроса. Есть несколько (например, 10 или 5000) записей в таблице. Первый раз юзеру выдается случайная. Когда он тычет в кнопку "дальше", надо выдавать опять случайную (для этого юзера), но без повторов. И все было бы хорошо, но записи периодически добавляются, юзеры регистрируются.

Попытки:

- глупое `WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ... ) ORDER BY RAND()` в запросе. Жалко сервер;
- `mt_srand` - сперва ID юзера, потом "ID предыдущего вопроса". Кроме зацикливания (если вдруг `mt_rand(N) == N`), не обеспечивает уникальность;
- `range(1, 99999) + shuffle` при регистрации и хранить в базе `json`-строку, каждый раз выбирая следующее. Подходит только для фиксированного количества записей (`arr[1]` может оказаться 39821 при 50 сообщениях в базе).

Пока склоняюсь к тому, что все-таки надо будет создавать кэш-таблицу для просмотренных записей вида "`ID_юзера | ID_записи`", а рандомную следующую выбирать на стороне php, примерно таким образом:

(`$records` - прочитанные сообщения вида $id => $id, `$nextID` - ID след. сообщения, `$total` - всего сообщений в базе)

1. При авторизации выбрать все айдишники просмотренных в сессию.
2. При показе очередной записи запустить `do { $nextID = mt_rand(1, $total); } while (isset($records[$nextID]));`
3. По кнопке "дальше" выбирается запись с `id=$nextID`, этот `$nextID` добавляется в список прочитанных и повторяется п. 2.

Достаточно ли это вменяемое решение или есть что-то более правильное/быстрое/легкое?

Answer (score 1):

Можно как вариант range(1, 99999) + *mt_srand* + shuffle (на самом деле shuffle использует другой rand, но суть думаю понятна). 
Seed брать из userId или sessionId.
Тогда в базе хранить ничего надо, т.к. shuffle будет всегда один и тот же для заданного seed'а.

Comment: Не можно :)

Первый элемент массива может оказаться 50000, а в базе 20 записей, например. + вы предлагаете нескольким сотням юзеров в сессии хранить массив из 100k элементов постоянно?)

Comment: Не нравится 100к - урежте количество записей для просмотра. Не нравится хранить в сессии - генерьте заново при обращении. Не нравится несколько несколько сот юзеров - храните шафлы не для каждого, а штук 10 для всех :)

Answer (score 0):

А кто заставляет выдавать именно случайную? Выдавайте по очереди. Откуда пользователю знать, что они неслучайные?:) Поверьте, для пользователя они будут выглядеть в любом случае случайно, если только у них нет явного номера в тексте.

Я бы создал (добавил) записям id, по возрастанию номера и выдавал. Если номер достиг максимума - сбрасывал на начальное значение. В сам текст записей добавил бы случайные номера для создания нужного эффекта.

Чтобы у разных пользователей не было одинаковых записей, можно выдавать первую запись случайно и хранить ее номер в куках/сессии. Если в базу будут добавлены новые записи - пользователь до них в любом случае дойдет. Можно для части пользователей идти в обратном направлении по номерам. Единственное, что нужно проработать, так это "дырку в последовательности id", если какую-то запись удалили, чтобы код корректно прошел ее.

Если этого недостаточно, можно нагенерировать несколько случайных последовательностей и выдавать согласно им. Просто при первом логине случайным образом присваивать одну из последовательностей. При добавлении новых записей эти последовательности нужно будет перегенерировать.

Comment: Тоже странный подход. Вот несколько последовательностей смысл имеет, но тоже для фиксированного количества записей. Ибо если при добавлении перегенерировать, надо будет все равно отмечать уже прочитанные в этой сгенерированной последовательности из прошлой. И чем тогда, спрашивается, хуже кэш-таблица, которую не надо перестраивать)

Вообще я осознаю, *что именно* мне надо, вопрос "про оптимизацию". "Поверить" тоже не могу, юзеры умеют в несколько акков, а некоторые и в ботов, так что, кроме как для показа фоток котиков, ваши варианты не подходят, к сожалению.